# Simultaneous multi widget animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

**Requirement**

In my Flutter application, I have 3 text widgets with texts "one", "two" and "three". I want to show them one at a time and the animation should look as follows:

- "one" slides from right(Offset(1,0)) to centre(Offset.zero) and stays there for 1 second
- then it slides from centre(Offset.zero) to left(Offset(-1,0)) while "two" slides from right to centre the same way "one" did.
- "two" stays there for another 1 second and we continue this repeatedly.

*The animation can be viewed [here](https://xoursing.com/all_products) on the top of the page.*

**What I tried:**

I tried using `AnimatedSwitcher` to achieve it like the following but it gives out unexpected results.

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
      reverseDuration: Duration(seconds: 0),
      transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
        return SlideTransition(
          position: Tween<Offset>(
            begin: Offset(3.0, 0.0),
            end: Offset(1, 0),
          ).animate(animation),
          child: child,
        );
      },
      child: SlideTransition(
        key: Key(texts[currentIdx]),
        position: Tween<Offset>(
          begin: Offset.zero,
          end: Offset(-3.0, 0.0),
        ).animate(_controller),
        child: Text(
          texts[currentIdx],
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

How can I achieve this animation?

Comment: the most easy would be `PageView.builder`

Comment: thats a great idea, I was able to achieve it with PageView.builder
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

@pskink made me realize I was looking in a totally wrong direction. I solved it using pageView.builder. Here's the code:

```
class _WordSliderState extends State<WordSlider> {
  List<String> texts = ["one", "two", "three"];
  late PageController _contoller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _contoller = PageController(
      keepPage: true,
    );
    Timer timer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 2), (_) {
      setState(() {
        _contoller.nextPage(
          curve: Curves.ease,
          duration: const Duration(seconds: 1),
        );
      
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _contoller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        height: 60,
        width: 120,
        child: PageView.builder(
          controller: _contoller,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return Text(
              texts[index % 3],
              style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: "DM_Sans",
                fontSize: 35,
              ),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}
```